# startActivity inside service is not working on all android devices

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, start-activity

I have to start an activity from FirebaseMessagingService and I invoke the following code when I receive a notification

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // some code here...

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When the app is in background and I receive a notification the result was

**Xiaomi mi a2:** MyActivity has been launched successfully.

**Xiaomi redmi note 7:** MyActivity not launched and nothing happened even not crashing.

Any help why starActivity is no working on all devices inside a background service, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Since what you are trying to do (start an activity from the background) is banned on Android 10, perhaps you should consider not doing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the user to still receive messages after the app has been killed - you can try using background services but since Android 10 bans background services as CommonsWare mentioned, and versions 8 & 9 both will kill background services after some time, you shouldn't rely on `onMessageReceived` when the app is killed. Instead, look into Firebase's `NotificationMessage` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications)

`NotificationMessage` is sent to the user and received no matter whether the device is in Doze mode or the app has been killed. This is probably the solution you're looking for - keeping background services running in Android 8+ is going to be difficult, and impossible in newer versions.